# find out all the line numbers with binary non-text chars of a big log file

Tags: grep

I have a big log file with non text chars. I used grep to search and I got this result:

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

I can use grep -a to skip these line with non text chars.

Now, how can I find out all lines which contain non-text chars ?

Answer (score 1):

What GNU `grep` considers non-text varies with the version and the locale.

In first approximation, you can try:

```
grep -anPe '^((?!.*$)|.*\0)' < file.log
```

That is look for the lines that contain a NUL character, 0 byte (likely to be the cause of that *Binary file* message if your log file was truncated while open for writing by some process without O_APPEND), or non-characters (possible if you're in a locale with a multibyte charset like UTF-8 and some lines were output in another charset).

That assumes your GNU `grep` was built with PCRE support (for `-P`).

You may want to pipe that output to something like `sed -n l` or `hexdump -C` or `od -vtc -tx1` (and maybe omit the `-n` option to `grep`) to try and identify those byte sequences that cause the *binary* message.

Note that `grep -a` does not skip those lines, it just tells GNU `grep` to not treat files it considers as *binary* specially. Lines with those 0 bytes or non-characters will still be reported if they match the pattern.

On Linux at least and most native filesystems, you can tell if a file is sparse, that is has unallocated parts (holes) that would appear full of zero bytes with:

```
perl -le '
  seek STDIN,0,4 or die; $hole = tell STDIN;
  seek STDIN, $hole, 3 and $data = tell STDIN;
  seek STDIN, 0, 2; $end = tell STDIN;
  if ($hole != $end) {
    print "at least one hole at offset $hole, length ".(($data||$end) - $hole)
  }' < file.log
```

*Holes* would be created whenever the gap would otherwise include at least one full filesystem block (typically 4KiB). There would probably be more NUL bytes on either side of those hole.